# Disable formatting in JOOQ when calling DSL.using(con).parser.parseStatement("select col1,col2 from table2")

Tags: jooq

When I call the following code

```
 DSL.using(SQLDialect.BIGQUERY).parser.parseStatement("select col1,col2 from table2")
```

Jooq formats the SQL statement and appends a new line like below

```
select col1,col2
from table2
```

is it possible to disable the formatting so that the output is

```
select col1,col2 from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

NVM, I figured out using the below code fixed the issue

```
DSL.using(SQLDialect.BIGQUERY).parser.parseQuery("select col1,col2 from table2").getSQL()
```